# why main method works without command line argument in java?

Tags: java

```
class Game {
   void game1(String ...s) {
        System.out.println("game1");
   }
   void game2(String s[] ) {
        System.out.println("game2");
   }

   public static void main(String []s) {
       new Game().game1();
       new Game().game2();
   }
}
```

why `main` method works without any command line argument in it but when you try to execute any other method with `String [] a` as argument it does not compile until we pass an argument in it, why ?

Comment: It's unclear what you mean - you're not *calling* the `main` method directly in your code... if you tried to call it from elsewhere, you'd have to pass in a reference to a string array. Note that your current `main` method *won't* compile because you're not passing a value to `game2()`. Additionally, please spend more time formatting your code before posting.

Comment: The java launcher **does** pass an array, but it is just empty

Answer (score 2):

When you call `main` from command line and enter no arguments, it is not equivalent to the call of `main()` with no parameters at all: it is equivalent to passing an array with zero elements, which is not the same thing.

When you pass no parameters, JVM creates an empty array of `String` objects, and passes it to your `main()`, like this:

```
main(new String[0]);
```

Note that an attempt to call `main` in code with zero parameters would lead to compile-time error in the same way that you get an error when you try calling `game2()` with no parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Essentially, `java.exe` (or `java` on Unix platforms) is a native executable implemented in `C` which initializes the JVM, loads the main class and calls the `static void main(String[])` method on the main class. This is implemented using the JNI API, and basically looks like

```
...
mainID = (*env)->GetStaticMethodID(env, mainClass, "main",
                                   "([Ljava/lang/String;)V");
CHECK_EXCEPTION_NULL_LEAVE(mainID);

/* Build platform specific argument array */
mainArgs = CreateApplicationArgs(env, argv, argc);
CHECK_EXCEPTION_NULL_LEAVE(mainArgs);

/* Invoke main method. */
(*env)->CallStaticVoidMethod(env, mainClass, mainID, mainArgs);
                                                     ^^^^^^^^
...
```

`CreateApplicationArgs()` creates an JNI data structure which represents a java array created from the `argv` and `argc` parameters which have been passed to the `C` `main` function in the first place. This array is empty when no command line arguments are given, but it is **always** passed to `main` when invoked through `CallStaticVoidMethod()`.

See (links might change in the future)

- http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/hs-rt/jdk/file/90773fb74728/src/java.base/share/native/libjli/java.c
- http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/hs-rt/jdk/file/90773fb74728/src/java.base/share/native/launcher/main.c

Answer (score 0):

The java executable passes an empty array of type `String` to the `main` method if no command line arguments are passed.